# Splitting web hosted video into chunks to stream

Tags: web, video, embed, video.js, m3u8

Hey I'm really hoping someone can help me with this as it would save me a lot of money on hosting

I have a file hosting provider which lets me store a couple hundred files for free as long as they're 10MB or less. These files are hosted publicly via a publicly accessible URL anyone can access.
I have some videos that are around 100-150MB in size that I'd like to put on my website.

I am on a very cheap web hosting plan which has a very small amount of disk space allocated to it which is quickly exceed if I uploaded them all there, so I'd like to host these videos somewhere else.

I got the idea of splitting the video into 10MB chunks which would be about 10-15 files and using a player like video.js https://videojs.com/ to play it back as a full video. I know this can be done via a .m3u8 file and some larger websites like Twitch clips actually play back videos exactly like this by loading it in segmented chunks instead of one entire single .MP4 file, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Essentially I'd embed the player on a webpage and have that player load a .m3u8 file or something similar which contains all the chunks of the video in the right order to play back seamlessly as it was a full video, that is my main goal, I just don't know how to go about making it a reality

Answer (score 0):

While I wasn't working with a disk space constraint, I did want to be able to serve large videos in a database. Since I only wanted to use a MEDIUMTEXT, I couldn't have more than 16MB of data in text. While it's not the ideal medium or format, it worked for what I needed it to. But this process would apply just the same to storing it in files.

I don't know what type of server you have, or what technologies you have available. However if you are able to serve a webpage, have intelligence behind it like with PHP or Node.js, read/write local files, and specify header information during the response, this is what you need to do.

Server:

1. Write a page that accepts a media ID, part ID, string with MIME type, int with total part count, and base64 encoded data. When part ID is 0, write a file called something like <media_id>*info.dat that contains the MIME type and part count. Then it, and each every other part, needs to take base64 encoded data, and write it to a file named something like <media_id>*<part_id>.dat
2. Write a page that accepts a media ID to be retrieved. It should read the <media_id>_info.dat file and then write the response header "Content-Type: <mime_type>". Then you read each part file, decode the base64, and output the raw contents in order.

Client:

1. Write a function, probably in JS that reads the file you want, and splits it up into your size limit but at 3/4 because base64 takes 4 bytes to store 3. For each part, call the server page to store the data read.

When the client requests the second server page, could be in a html video tag as the src attribute, all it sees is the raw data you output, it can't tell you are reading the data originally from multiple files.

Comment: If your files are size constrained, then encoding them as base64 is not a good idea. And I don't see why is that needed at all. And the server will probably attempt at making [HTTP range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests), so you would probably also want to implement that.